# SQL unknown column when doing join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been getting an error "Unknown column 'guests_guest.id' in 'field list'" when i try to run the following:

```
SELECT guests_guest.id
FROM `guests_guest` full join
guests_guest_group
on guests_guest.id=guests_guest_group.guest_id
```

All the column& table names are correct. in fact, running just

```
SELECT guests_guest.id
FROM `guests_guest`
```

works just fine. I suspect there is a syntax issue I am missing. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: The backticks are unnecessary, since none of your field/table names used reserved words.

Comment: Anybody else start thinking "guest" was a weird word after reading it......seventeen times?

Comment: New ORM - guests is the project name, guest is many to many related to groups, these are the table names it generated. Next time, ill pick more unique names in my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT gg.id
FROM `guests_guest` as gg
join guests_guest_group as ggg
on ggg.guest_id=gg.id
```

assuming guests_guest_group does not have an id column.

Comment: It works but it does not produce same result set as the FULL JOIN you (prehaps) want.

Comment: Goodness gracious gee golly gosh!

Answer (score 2):

`full join` ?

Have you tried simply removing the `full`?

This not Oracle, it's MySQL, right? AFAIK, FULL JOIN is not implemented yet in MySQL.

The parser (because "full' is not a keyword it knows), evaluates your query as:

```
SELECT guests_guest.id
FROM guests_guest AS full                 <--- crucial note
  JOIN guests_guest_group
    ON guests_guest.id = guests_guest_group.guest_id
```

After that, `guests_guest` is not a name it knows, but it uses `full` as an alias for table `guests_guest`. That's why this error is produced.

If you really need `FULL JOIN` and not (INNER) `JOIN`, then search SO for how to implement FULL JOIN in MYSQL.

Comment: Agreed. AS is optional in the table alias.  `ON guests_guest.id = full.guest_id` would work in this case, although it would be somewhat confusing. =D

Answer (score 0):

@rockerest:  I guest so.

Two things I'd look at:

1. Spelling... I am a fast typer, but sometimes my fingers are dyslexic.  Worst case, do a describe on each table and check column names against each other.  Or, use the system-confessed column names and copy/paste.
2. Aliases... but, someone else has mentioned that.

So I guessed just one thing.

Comment: You guest one thing?  You should compile more guestes before you submit an answer.  What if you have to edit it a bunch of times to add new guestes?  Then it becomes a wiki and everybody loses.